# Adding an active class to a react element to be able to change css

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do is to be able to toggle an active class on my elements that are dynamically created, as to be able to change the css for the selected checkbox, giving the impression that a certain filter is selected. I have looked at so many solutions and guides to make this work for my app, but I can't seem to implement it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Checkboxes component

```
    import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = (props) => {
  const { label, subKey } = props;
  const sub1 = `${subKey}1`;

  return (
    <label htmlFor={sub1} className="check_label">
      {label} 
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={sub1}
        checked={props.isChecked}
        onChange={props.handleCheck}
        onClick={() => console.log(label)}
        value={`${label.toLowerCase()}/?search=`}
      />
    </label>
  );
};
export default Checkbox;
```

and the Search component that implements checkboxes

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';

const APIQuery = 'https://swapi.co/api/';
const searchLabels = ['Planets', 'Starships', 'People', 'Species', 'Films', 'Vehicles'];


export default class Searchbutton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      endpointValue: '',
      searchValue: '',
    };
  }

  /* Funcionality to handle form and state of form */
  /* Changes state of value whenever the form is changed, in realtime. */
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
  }

  /* Prevents default formsubmit */
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  /* Handles state of checkboxes and sets state as to prepend necessary filter for request */
  handleCheck(event) {
    this.setState({ endpointValue: event.target.value });
    if (this.state.endpointValue === event.target.value) {
      this.setState({ endpointValue: '' });
    }
  }

  /* Creates the checkboxes dynamically from the list of labels. */

  createBoxes() {
    const checkboxArray = [];
    searchLabels.map(item => checkboxArray.push(
      <Checkbox
        key={item}
        className="madeBoxes"
        subKey={item}
        endpointValue={this.state.endpointValue}
        handleChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        handleCheck={e => this.handleCheck(e)}
        label={item}
      />,
    ));
    return checkboxArray;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search_content">
        <div className="search_wrapper">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="#">
            <label htmlFor="searchBar">
              <input type="text" id="searchbar" className="search_bar" value={this.state.searchValue} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
            </label>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" className="search_button" value="May the Force be with you." onClick={() => this.props.searchWithApi(APIQuery + this.state.endpointValue + this.state.searchValue)} />
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>

        <div className="checkboxes">
          {this.createBoxes(this.labels)}
        </div>

        <div className="sort_filters">
          {' '}
          {/* These are options that the user can make in order to sort and filter the results.
          The idea is to make it so that changing the value auto-perform a new request */}
          {/* For sorting the returned objects based on user choice */}
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid, until href added */}
          <a href="#" className="sort_button">Choose sort method</a>
          <ul className="sorting">
            <li className="sort_optn" href="#" value="lexicographical">Alphabetically</li>
            <li className="sort_optn" href="#" value="by_added_date">By added date</li>
            <li className="sort_optn" href="#" value="by_added_date_rev">By added date reversed</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maintain one flag in searchLabels

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do it with react. You can reformat your code a little bit and solve it with CSS `:checked` pseudo-class.

In particular, don't wrap your checkbox within a label, but instead put the label after the input. Check this fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/8c7a0fx5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the styled-component package. check the example below on how to use it:

```
    import { Component } from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'
    import styled from 'styled-components'

    const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
      label {
         background: ${props => props.active ? 'red': 'white'}
      }
    `

    class MyAwesomeComponent extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
          isChecked: false
        }
        this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
      }

      handleOnChange = ()=>{
        this.setState({
          isChecked: !this.state.isChecked,
        })
      }

      render(){
       const { isChecked } = this.state

        return(
          <StyledCheckbox active={isChecked}>
            <label>Names</label>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
          </StyledCheckbox>
        )
      }
    }

   render(<MyAwesomeComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Working code on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lomse/pen/Rqpxwr)